# Paste Data to a Table Using Excel Macro Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste a range of data from one workbook to another transposed. Let's say I already have data copied to my clipboard using Excel macro code... How would it be best to make sure the data gets pasted in another workbook, on a specific sheet and must be in a new row in a table where the new row may have to be created still (the table needs to be expanded down a row)? I have looked and looked through to no avail have I found a question quite like the one I'm trying to solve. The code I have so far is as follows but it only pastes to the same location and doesn't take into account for data already present in the table.

```
Sub Devs_ImportData_2()
'
' Devs_ImportData_and_CreateTable_1 Macro
'
'

    Windows("DevVariables.txt").Activate
    Range("D3:D543").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("B_1_2 DevConfiguration.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Devs"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "D1"
    Range("A1:TV2").Select


    Columns("A:TV").EntireColumn.AutoFit


    Windows("DevVariables.txt").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the clipboard to achieve this. You can iterate over all selected cells in workbook A, and insert the contents into a cell in workbook B. You can then determine your action per cell.

otherwise, use your paste like this:

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

EDIT:

I have created an example to demonstrate the transposition of a selected range into another workbook, where the selected data will be inserted at the selected row in the target workbook. This example uses an array instead of the clipboard.

```
Sub insertrange()
Dim sourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i, j As Long

Set sourceSheet = Application.Workbooks(2).Sheets(1)
Set targetSheet = Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)

sourceSheet.Activate

ReDim arr(Selection.Rows.Count - 1, Selection.Columns.Count - 1)

For i = 0 To Selection.Rows.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To Selection.Columns.Count - 1
        arr(i, j) = Selection.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value
    Next
Next

targetSheet.Activate

Dim selectedCell As Excel.Range
Set selectedCell = Selection

Dim rowOffset As Long
rowOffset = selectedCell.row

For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)

    targetSheet.Rows(rowOffset + i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    For j = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
        targetSheet.Cells(i + rowOffset, j + 1).Value = arr(i, j)
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Below are screenshots of how I have prepared the sheets, and the result after running the above code. Some additions and changes need to be made, like a column offset as well as the row offset, and just copying values might not be enough. You might need formulas or more complex stuff, but the basics are there.

[source book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuwUj.png)

[target book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVjeJ.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2lsi.png)

Comment: I agree and I know I should avoid using the clipboard for the goals in this question but alas I am inept and am still learning Visual Basic. Would you care to expand more on the answer you provided?